# Issue in Server.Target while navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a .net application using twitter bootstrap.

I'm navigating from Default1.aspx to Default2.aspx using `Server.Target` and on the page load of Default2.aspx, i'm saving Default2.aspx page as html page and mailing that html file to the user. I'm facing some issues here.
After sending mail to the user, it should be back to Default1.aspx.

**Here is my code**

**Default.aspx:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNavigate" Text="Navigate to Default2.aspx" 
runat="server" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" OnClick="btnNavigate_Click">
</asp:Button>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnNavigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Items.Add("Id", "10");
        string targetPath = "~/Reports/Default2.aspx";
        Server.Transfer(targetPath);
    }
```

**Default2.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      if (Context.Items["Id"] != null)
      {
        int Id=Convert.ToInt32(Context.Items["Id"]);
        if (SendDashboardHTMLfileAsEmail(Id)==true)
        {
           Context.Items.Add("TestId", Id.ToString());
           string targetPath = "~/Reports/Default1.aspx";
           Server.Transfer(targetPath);
        }
      }
    }
   }
private void SendDashboardHTMLfileAsEmail(int Id)
  {
  //create Default2.aspx page as html file in a path
  //Send a email to user with an attachment        
  //newly created html file is the attachment
  }
```

I'm getting an error **Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack** while i'm navigating to Default1.aspx page.

After sending mail to the user it is not getting navigated to Default1.aspx,but it is in Default2.aspx still.

Please help me out.

Comment: It should work.Lat you check that targetPath folder structure correct

Comment: I think your solution is fundamentally flawed. Why do you have to navigate to a different page to create html and send out email. You can do that from page1 itself. Look for some token based html processing library, then have a html file with some token to replace values. But if you still want to stick to your current solution then use PreviousPage property to access variable/values etc. Like shown here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Reports/Default1.aspx", false);
```

However, you cannot use Context to transfer information to the next page, use `Session` instead:

```
Session["Id"] = 10;
```

To retrieve the information on the next page, use a cast on the `Session` object

```
var Id = (int)Session["Id"];
```

Comment: How about this: Response.Redirect("~/Reports/Default1.aspx", false)

Comment: im getting the same error with `Response.Redirect("~/Reports/Default1.aspx");` instead we need to use `Response.Redirect("~/Reports/Default1.aspx",false);`